# How to create chef cookbook in git repository?

Tags: git, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am a beginner in chef. I wanted to create a cookbook in git repository from the command line.

Currently I am using the syntax :

```
c:\Users\chef-repo\demo_1\chef\site-cookbooks>git add cookbook
```

But it gives me an error.

What would be the correct command-line sequence to use here?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: It  gives me an error : fatal: pathspec 'cookbooks' did not match any files

Comment: No need to add: simply `git clone https://github.com/chef/chef-repo` and try chef stuff in that local cloned repo.

Comment: That is what my answer is for: use `knife`: it is meant to add new cookbooks. But first, clone the `chef/chef-repo`.

Comment: @Vonc : Thank you ! that was not it though , I wanted to create a new cookbook in the repository  . i got to know how to do that using the syntax : Chef generate cookbook <cookbook_name>

Comment: That is what my answer is for: use `knife`: it is meant to add new cookbooks. But first, clone the `chef/chef-repo`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you created a blank repo on your remote... (eg: Github or Gitlab)

`$ git clone [... cookbookname.git]`

`$ cd cookbookname`

`$ berks cookbook cookbookname .`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 1):

A typical blank chef repo (like [`chef/chef-repo`](https://github.com/chef/chef-repo)) doesn't have a file '`cookbook`'.
It has a folder '`cookbooks/`'.

See [About the chef-repo](https://docs.chef.io/chef_repo.html):

> The `chef-repo` is the location in which the following data objects are stored:
>
> - Cookbooks (including recipes, versions, cookbook attributes, resources, providers, libraries, and templates)
> - Roles
> - Data bags
> - Environments
> - Configuration files (for clients, workstations, and servers)

To add a cookbook in the `cookbooks/` folder, you would use [`knife`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html).

```
knife cookbook create COOKBOOK
```

Comment: can cookbooks be added only using knife .. i thought you can also do it from Git

Comment: @ErPujaBhattacharya if you mean the folder `cookbooks/`, it is already added since it is part of the repo `chef/chef-repo` that you can clone.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're taking `git` as a chef tool.

`Git` is a versionning system (as svn for exemple), it is not chef specific.

`Knife` is used to create a cookbook skeleton, this is not mandatory, but it helps you create the correct directory structure and creates the `metada.rb` with correct attributes too.

I highly recommend reading https://learn.chef.io/fundamentals-series/ to get an overview over Chef before playing with chef-dk and `chef generate cookbook` which goes deeper in the cookbook creation as it integrate unit test and some other tooling which could complicate the first understanding.

---

For your specific question I would understand as: "How to create a cookbook in a specific directory (not in the `cookbook_path` attribute of `knife.rb`)"

You can use `knife cookbook create NAME_OF_COOKBOOK -o PATH_WHERE_TO_CREATE`

The `PATH_WHERE_TO_CREATE` could be `.` if you want to create a cookbook in the current directory.

Once the cookbook is created you can version it with `git init` and then `git add`. You may wish to add a remote repository with `git remote add REMOTE_REPO_NAME REMOTE_REPO_URL` to avoid loosing your work.

Take time to go through some tutorials about git if you're not familiar with it, you'll save time.